# Why am I getting a "Title set but using a system Identifier" warning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, storyboard, uistoryboard

I get the following warning:

> MainStoryboard.storyboard: Title set but using a system Identifier
>   (These attributes are mutually exclusive; the Title will be ignored)

I have a manually placed toolbar on my storyboard with a Title and a Cancel button. What's wrong about that?

Comment: the error message is pretty informative

Comment: It may be informative, but it's cryptic and confusing. Thanks to the answer below, I was able to find how to correct the problem. The strange thing is that the title was set in the Inspector, but not by me, hence my confusion as to why this was happening.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Are you adding a title to the Cancel button (e.g. “Cancel”)?

You don’t need to do this as setting the bar button item as a system bar button item (like Cancel) will automatically set the title—and it’ll be localized for you.

Comment: Thank you! Not sure why Xcode automatically filled in "Item" for title and then left it in place when I changed from "Custom" to "Cancel", but clearing out the title fixed it.