# Compiler Warnings Unsupported Configuration. Can't Find Controller Causing Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

I have a couple of compile warnings

> Unsupported Configuation 
>   Title set but using a system Identifier
>   (These attributes are mutually exclusive; the Title will be ignored)

But I can't seem to find the controller that is causing this error. Clicking on the error itself in Xcode doesn't do anything.

How can I find which scene is causing this problem in my storyboard?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15466451/why-am-i-getting-a-title-set-but-using-a-system-identifier-warning

Answer (score 1):

Using the methodology specified in [Storyboard - Unsupported configuration 8 conflicting constrains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520765/storyboard-unsupported-configuration-8-conflicting-constrains)

Click on the 'Log Navigator' tab, select the relevant build log and locate the issues.  Expand the details (click on the striped lines icon far right next to the line's error count).  There will be a line similar to:

/path/to/Main.storyboard:vyg-ce-VV4: warning: Title set but using a system Identifier (These attributes are mutually exclusive; the Title will be ignored)

The part between the colons between the storyboard path and the warning (vyg-ce-VV4 in this case) is the ID of the constraint that caused the issue.

Right click on your storyboard file in the project navigator, then 'Open As -> Source Code' and search for the ID of the constraint in the XML. That will allow you to see the view and item generating the problem. Right-click the storyboard and select 'Open As -> Interface Build - iOS Storyboard' to switch back to the UI to fix the issue.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.